# How to switch to another pipeline in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

I have two subjects:

```
const foo = new Subject();
const bar = new Subject();
```

And each of them acting different:

```
const foo$ = foo.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in foo');
  })
);

const bar$ = bar.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in bar');
  }),
);
```

When I call `bar.next` to trigger the `bar$` pipeline and it's of course works as expected.

But I want to trigger the `foo$` pipeline within the `bar$` pipeline like that:

```
const foo$ = foo.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in foo');
  })
);

const bar$ = bar.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in bar');
  }),
  switchMap(() => foo$)
);
```

This not working.

I have some limitations:

1. I don't want to trigger the subject because it trigger every subscribers somewhere in the app.
2. I can't use `foo$.next` because it's `next` don't exist in `foo$`.
3. I want to use `foo$` in the same pipeline of `bar$` using the pipeline.

I try to wrap it in `from`, `switchMap`, `map`, `switchMapTo` - those not working.

Any idea?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-eqcnsz?devtoolsheight=60)

```
import { Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

const foo = new Subject();
const bar = new Subject();

const foo$ = foo.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in foo');
  })
);

const bar$ = bar.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in bar');
  }),
  switchMap(() => foo$)
);

bar$.subscribe();

bar.next(1);
```

Comment: It's very unclear to me what doesn't work and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have an active inner subscription to `foo$`, but it's not emitting anything because that can only be done with your `bar` Subject. (Which you say that you don't want to trigger.)

So the next best thing is to combine both your `foo` subject and the `bar$` observable as the source of your `foo$` observable. Because we don't know when either observable will emit or complete, we'll use the `mergeWith()` operator.

```
import { Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

const foo = new Subject();
const bar = new Subject();

const fooSource$ = foo.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in foo');
  })
);

const barSource$ = bar$.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    // do whatever before bar$ emits to foo$
  })
);

const foo$ = fooSource$.pipe(
  mergeWith(barSource$),
  tap(() => {
    // do whatever before foo$ emits its value
  })
);

const bar$ = bar.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('in bar');
  })
);

bar$.subscribe();

bar.next(1);
```

Note that with `mergeWith()` you cannot distinguish which observable is triggering the emit. So it's a good idea to have both `fooSource$` and `barSource$` emit the same value type.

Comment: The way you use mergeWith is different from merge. I updated my answer to include this change.

Comment: Okay, but I don't want to invoke `foo`. in your code i need to both of them to be invoke in order to run the foo pipeline..

Comment: I think if rxjs have an operator which tell the `foo$` to subscribe and emit a value from the bar pipeline it's be working. but I don't know such an operator. do you?

Comment: You do not need to invoke both. When you merge `fooSource$` and `barSource$`, you only need to invoke one to have `foo$` emit it's value.

Comment: Well, it's doesn't work. and I want to avoid duplication of the pipe. ` foo.pipe(` should use in the case of `bar.next` and `foo.next`

Comment: Here's a StackBlitz link with the above code applied to an example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdwqgz?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts It's using Angular, but the comopnent's TS file has the same RxJS pipes setup there. You can click a button to have a subject emit a value. If you click on `Foo Subject`, it applies the obvious effect in having `foo` and `foo$` emit a value. But if you click the `Bar Subject` it will also trigger `foo$` to emit a new value without any activity from the `foo` subject.